# Why is my Pokémon not at its max potential CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a 100IV Dragonite (Double-checked, and it comes out with the top valued appraisal, included good Stam, Atk and Def) and I am Level 39. My Dragonite is only 3531CP, and the HP is in fact 154HP,  but the maximum should be 3581CP and the Power-Up Button has disappeared (meaning that it will not Power-Up anymore). Is there a good reason for this?

P.S. Also, note that it was caught as Pokémon level 39.

Unlike this post here:

[In Pokemon Go, will aiming for the highest IV give the highest CP as well?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281658/in-pokemon-go-will-aiming-for-the-highest-iv-give-the-highest-cp-as-well),

I cannot Power Up anymore, so Trainer Level doesn't count here.

Comment: Where did you catch a Pokemon at level 39? Hatched Pokemon have a maximum level of 20, wild Pokemon have a maximum level of 30. Or am I reading this wrong and *you* were at Trainer level 39 when you caught the Pokemon, whose caught-at-level you don't actually know?

Comment: @scenia, yeah correct. I was at LVL 39 when I caught the dratini (it was evolved)

Comment: According to Poke Assistant's IV calculator, 100% Dragonite at level 39 would be CP 3530, at 39.5 would be CP 3556.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "top valued appraisal, included *good* Stam, Atk and Def", is the sentence used to describe the best stats "*It's stats exceed my calculations*" (Mystic), "*I'm blown away by it's stats*" (Valor) or "*It's stats are the best I've ever seen*" (Instinct)? Because if it's "*I'm certainly impressed by its stats*" (Mystic), "*It's got excellent stats*" (Valor) or "*Its stats are really strong*" (Instinct), then it's not actually 100%, but either 13/13/13 or 14/14/14. Also, is its HP 154 or 155?

Comment: No, I used an IV Calculator _and_ appraisal (to get an approximation), and I certainly got 100IV. Also, it is _It's stats exceed my calculations._(Mystic) HP I am not sure of, because the account is not actually mine, but my family's so I currently have no access. @scenia

Comment: Ok, then could you double check the numbers when you get access again? I've tried a few variations and 3541 isn't actually possible at all, no matter the IVs...

Comment: Yeah, I am sure @scenia

Comment: Can you still double check? After some more playing around with the calculators, I found out 3541 CP is in fact possible, but only at level 40 with 153 HP and IVs of 14/15/12. So either your memory is wrong or your game is displaying wrong information. A 15/15/15 Dragonite can never have 3541 CP.

Comment: @scenia , wait two weeks! I will reply in two. Thanks! I am sure it is 100IV, but maybe HP is wrong

Comment: @scenia, you are right, I have remembered wrong. =)

Comment: With the new CP/HP values, your dragonite is (14, 15, 10) at level 40; very good!  You have also answered the question about a pokemon's maximum level, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably know, you are able to level up your Pokémon twice per trainer level. However, it appears that a Pokémon reaching level 40.0 is a bug that was performed by [pressing the Power Up button with 2-3 fingers](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ra5z0/double_tap_triple_tap_strategy_how_to_proceed/?ref=search_posts), but it has [since been removed](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5un4m0/pokemon_max_level_after_gen_2_update/?ref=search_posts).

Thus, you're only able to power your Pokémon up to level **39.0** these days without the bug. Due to the fact that you're always able to level your Pokémon up to your trainer level + 1.5, your Pokémon will hit their max level when you're trainer level 38 after being powered up one last time. From [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5xltxm/is_there_any_indication_that_niantic_will_fix_max/?ref=search_posts):

> There was the well known double/triple tap trick to get Pokemon to level 40 if you were already at level 38 and didn't power your Pokemon to 39 (and having the power up bar go away). [...] the gen 2 patches have eliminated that

Comment: @simplest_mathematics I can't answer for the downvote since it wasn't me. However, I think you misread my answer. I'm not saying *your* client is bugged, I'm saying that everyone who referred to the max level of 40.0 for Pokémon was mistaken as that was an unintentional maximum level. The maximum level appears to *actually* be 39.0. After leveling up the final time at trainer level 38, your Power Up option should disappear since your Pokémon can no longer be leveled up. Originally, you could use 3 fingers to Power up 3 times at once before the option disappeared, powering your mon up to 40.0.

Comment: That is, the calculation for maximum CP is displaying a number higher than what is actually achievable, as it's impossible to get a Pokémon to level 40.0 after the patch to remove the exploit that I've mentioned. What you have currently is likely the *real* maximum.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics look at the very first sentence of my first comment. But in general, it's not considered "good form" to ask about a single downvote and can potentially attract more.

Comment: ...and a single downvote without any explanatory comment is also relatively "bad form", and the wisest response is to behave like a well-mannered person observing poor manners: pretend it didn't happen.